# Did the dragons of Chinese mythology originate from tornadoes?

Tags: chinese, dragons

I remember reading that tornadoes disappeared from ancient Asia due to climate change, and so the memory of it is preserved in myth as dragons. Is this true?

Comment: This isn't an issue anymore because your question seems to have been answers, but in the future you should name the book/article where you `"remember reading that tornadoes disappeared..."` It's much easier for us to answer your questions if we have the name of a book: that way we have a starting place for our research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origin of dragons in the Eastern tradition is disputed. The leading explanation is perhaps that the dragon was originally crocodiles. However, one proposed alternative *does* argue that dragons (`龍`) was historically a word describing tornadoes.

> In Chinese scholarship, there are mainly two hypotheses concerning the essential characteristics of the dragon. One hypothesis aims to find a real prototype of the dragon. This hypothesis often identifies the dragon with a crocodile, **tornado**, or lightning, or even the river.
>
> **<sub>- Yang, Lihui, and Deming An. *Handbook of Chinese Mythology.* Abc-clio, 2005.</sub>**

It has been argued that the original meaning became gradually lost and shrouded in myth as the natural phenomenon disappeared, and was eventually re-imaged as a fearsome mythical beast.

The main proponent is probably is Dr. Benjamin Chao, a former director of the Institute of Earth Sciences at the [Academia Sinica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academia_Sinica) in Taiwan. He has published this idea in the Chinese version of the [*Scientific American*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_American) magazine. Not exactly a scientifically rigorous theory, but it has its adherents.

The original article can be found [here](http://www.earth.sinica.edu.tw/~bfchao/publication/cht/201005-099.pdf) from the Academia Sinica.